# Rollback to Arctic Fox from Bumblebee

Tags: android, android-studio

Bumblebee is creating lot of problem with emulator. How can i roll back to Arctic fox from Bumblebee, as bumblebee has many issues with emulator

I just want that i dont need to uninstall the bumblebee, and i just want to go back to Arctic fox

Answer (score 0):

You can download any previous version of Android studio from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive) and run it alongside the stable build as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it's possible to rollback, you can just save your configs while uninstall your current Android Studio version and then download previous one from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive).